# sql query to show records created today, last week and last month

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write some sql queries to show me records from mysql database that are created today, records created last week, and records created last month..The first query show me results created in last 7 days (including today). For example if today is Sunday, I want to see results created from Monday to Saturday (not today). Similarly, in the second query I want to see records created last month (excluding records of this month). For example, if this is June, I want to see records created in May

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS stdtotal FROM `login` 
WHERE `account_created_date`  > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

and the other query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS stdtotal FROM `login` 
WHERE `account_created_date`  > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Note that my table name is `login` and the column name is `account_created_date` of type date.

Comment: What's the problem. You've got result as you expected.

Comment: The first query show me results created in last 7 days (including today). For example if today is Sunday, I want to see results created from Monday to Saturday. Similarly, in the second query I want to see records created last month (excluding records of this month). For example, if this is June, I want to see records created in May.

Comment: So, you have to use `WHERE SomeDateField BETWEEN OneDate AND SecondDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix the `where` clauses.  For the previous 7 days:

```
WHERE account_created_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND
      account_created_date < CURDATE()
```

For the previous month:

```
WHERE account_created_date >= DATE_SUB(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE) - 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) AND
      account_created_date < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE) - 1 DAY)
```

This calculates the first day of the current month and then goes one month prior to that.

Comment: can you please help me to show records created this month?

Comment: `WHERE account_created_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL DAY(CURDATE) - 1 DAY)`.